# How to implement webrtc in android Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, websocket, webrtc, ktor, webrtc-android

I am creating a  random Chat application using `ktor` and `websocket` , I successfully implemented the random chat system , when user press search add that user to the queue and wait for the other user to join and exchange their id's so that we can start sending data back and forth

now I also want to setup video calling system , I want when `Clint1` press search  , it creates a `webrtc`  OFFER and send that offer to my `KTOR` server where I m managing my waiting `Queue or Websocket` and when `Chint2`  is join I want to establish a video call by sending `Clint2`  a offer that `clint1` is generated

I never use webrtc before so i dont know how to do that , I just want  suppose we have two clints .

clind1 and clint2 generate their offers and exchange their `ids or roomId's` something like that using websocket or just start video calling